# How can I incorporate keyframes to multiple elements?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

...or do I even need to?
I have a navbar that changes once you start scrolling down the page. A few different elements are affected. Right now I am using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var change = $('.banner');
    var offset = change.offset();
    if (change.length)
    {
        $(document).scroll(function()
        {
            scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (scroll_start > offset.top)
            {
                $(".navbar").css('background-color', '#000');
                $(".nav-item a").css('color', "#27AAE2");
                $('.logo-img').css({
                'height':'30px',
                'width':'215px'
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $(".nav-item a").css('color', "#FFF");
                $('.logo-img').css({
                'height':'45px',
                'width':'310px'
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works just fine. But I would like the transition to be animated rather than just an instant change. I have seen this done with keyframes, but only ever using one element.

Just hoping for some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: post the codepen url  to see your current output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I answered my own question.
I created keyframes and then added those keyframes from the jquery.

Within the keyframes I can make every change I can imagine...with only a single call to that class from the jquery.